# Why does this incorrect compilation and linkage result in a deletion of my C source file?

Tags: c

I have noticed that an erroneous compilation and linkage command results in the deletion of one of my C source files.

Assume I have 2 source files and a header file: `test1.c`, `test2.c`, and `header.h`. I then erroneously attempt to compile and link these files with the shell command `cc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o test1.c test2.c`.

Due to this erroneous command, I get the error message:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main", referenced from: implicit entry/start for main executable ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`.

After this, the file `test1.c` is deleted.

I am curious as to what's causing the deletion and why?

Comment: `-o test1.c`. The `-o` option tells the compiler to put the output into that file. Something that you could work out yourself if you just read [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html)

Comment: What in the gcc documentation about the `-o` option was unclear?

Comment: @Olaf Where in the documentation does it explain the reason behind this deletion? I wasn't asking what `-o` does. I was asking why it chooses to delete the file, instead of just leaving it and printing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is outputting to `test1.c`, the command fails and therefore effectively deletes the file.

```
cc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o output test1.c test2.c
                                     ^ the output flag
```

I've modified your command to output the program to `./output`.

---

[Edited due to further question in comments]

To the question of why `cc` deletes the file: I ran `strace -f cc -o test1.c test2.c` to find out more about what it was doing. At some point in the output of strace you see this line:

```
[pid XXXXX] unlink("test1.c")           = 0
```

`unlink` will delete a file, read more at `man 3 unlink`.

I believe the reason `cc` deletes the file is `cc` thinks it is creator of the file, and therefore is trying to clean up after itself.

Comment: So when it fails to output into `test1.c`, it will just delete the target file and terminate?

Comment: So, at some point during `cc ...` the program opens up `test1.c` in the following mode `open("test1.c", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666)` which means that it truncates the file to 0. It then runs `unlink("test1.c")` which deletes the file. 

If you want to see this for yourself you can run this command: `strace -f cc -o test1.c test2.c &> output; grep "test1.c" output` -- which shows you the system calls. You can also read more on `man unlink`. I think it does this because CC believe it is the creator of the file, and therefore is trying to clean up after itself.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @ThePointer - if you had syntax errors, it won't delete `test1.c`. What actually occurred is that `gcc` compiled `test2.c`. It never compiled `test1.c` being an output destination. It then called `ld` to link the object file stored in temporary directory with random filename. `ld` cleaned out the output destination and couldn't find `main()` from `test1.c` which was never compiled to begin with. Running `strace -f gcc -o test1.c test2.c` will reveal it.

Comment: @alvits Illuminating response. Thank you.

Comment: oh nevermind. @ScottGreenup beat me to it ... by 6 minutes.

Comment: @alvits Leave your comment. It is good to have multiple explanations of the same concept. :)

Comment: @alvits It's a good point though, it only occurs due to `cc` failing.

Comment: @ScottGreenup The `strace` commands supplied by yourself and alvits does not seem to be working. Alvits' command gives the error `-bash: strace: command not found`. Your command creates a file called `output`, which contains the text `-bash: strace: command not found`. Any idea how I can fix this? My OS is OS X, if that helps.

Comment: @alvits Above is related.

Comment: @ThePointer - Either you are not running Linux or `strace` package is not installed.

Comment: Ah, right -- strace is something more specific to linux. You'll need to find an equivalent for OSX; and read it's documentation about how it works. https://www.google.com.au/search?num=50&q=OSX+strace